# How to increase the vertical size of a JList parallel with the addition of the elements

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList of having a vertical size enough for one element(image 1)

when an element is added it looks like as(image 2)

But what I need is this (image 3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the vertical size of the JList to be increased when an extra element is added.This should continue until the vertical size of the JList reaches its limit. (say 200) 
Is there any way to overcome this problem?

I tried using,

```
        DefaultListModel<String> dl = new  DefaultListModel<>();
    dl.addListDataListener(new ListDataListener() {

        @Override
        public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
            System.out.println("content changed");
        }
    });
    jList1.setModel(dl);
```

but nothing is going to happen when elements are added ( no output )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setVisibleRowCount(...)` method of JList to control the preferred size of the `JList`.

So then you will need to add a `ListDataListener` to the `ListModel` of the `JList` to listen for changes in the data. Whenever a `contentChanged` event is generated you would reset the visible row count of the `JList`.

You would need to restrict the row count to a reasonable maximum, like maybe 20.

Comment: @LahiruJ, looks like you need to listen for the intervalAdded and intervalRemoved events as well. Can't believe you didn't this to try that on your own. You learn more by experimenting.